# Labeling specific countries using Natural Earth and QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, natural-earth

I am new to QGIS 3 and want to make a simple map of research area. I'm using Natural Earth and I've identified the *"10m_admin_0_map_units"* is the file with the country names.

I just want a few country names to appear on the map of the Caribbean e.g. Barbados, Curacao, Cuba, Venezuela, Mexico. But I can't work out how to set up the rule based layer for this and I can't find a tutorial using this Version.

Could someone explain how I set-up the filter to only get a few country names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should to use in Properties --> Label --> Rendering --> Show Label

[image]

Click on "Edit..." and add the next expresion:

"name" in
 ( 'Venezuela' , 'Cuba' , 'Mexico' )

This is the result
[image]